# How do I echo the text of one input element to another input element in the same form using PHP and HTML?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have two input elements:

1. one for typing
2. another for display the submitted text as a tag

These two input elements are on the same form.

I would like for a user to enter text into the first input element and then when they press "enter" on the keyboard the text is displayed in the second input field as a tag.

In the second input element I tried to execute this code but it is not working:
   " />

Note: I am using Bootstrap 3 library.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why PHP - does the server need to handle this information in any way? If not, this is a problem you can solve with JavaScript on the client's side of things. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/r36L8jnw/

Answer (score 1):

use JS or jQuery for it.(something like this 
`$('#yourelement').on('keyup',function(event){.....}));` 
issues like this should be solved on client side, not on serverside using PHP.
to solve this issue with html+PHP only, you have to reload the page all the time after Enter press (you have to make a form and on Enter form will be submitted, then get this data in PHP and put in form again, BUT this is really bad way programming)

Answer (score 0):

It won't work with PHP. PHP does not run in the browser only on the server side when the page is loaded.  You need to use a client side language.